# React testing-library: File object is empty while testing file (image) upload?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a unit test for a file (image) upload using test-library for React, however, when I log the file in the console it shows an empty object. I am not sure if there is any path configuration required. The image is located in the same directory as test `src/util/tests/`.

Here is my code:

```
const file = new File(["logo"], "logo.png", { type: "image/png" });
const imageComponent = screen.getByLabelText(/Profile Picture/i);

console.log(file);
userEvent.upload(imageComponent, file);

console.log(imageComponent.files[0]);
expect(imageComponent.files[0]).toStrictEqual(file);
expect(imageComponent.files.item(0)).toStrictEqual(file);
expect(imageComponent.files).toHaveLength(1);
```

Here is my console output:

```
console.log
File {}

at Object.<anonymous> (src/util/tests/Register.test.js:54:11)

console.log
File {}
at Object.<anonymous> (src/util/tests/Register.test.js:57:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. So i post for the next one. Found solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973296/4827578

Blob is not supported in node. Add a polyfill :

`yarn add blob-polyfill -D`

and then import the following in your jest `setupTests`:

`import 'blob-polyfill';`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue too. I think there are two (maybe three?) issues:

1. `console.log()` isn't showing you all of the properties of the File object ([see this related issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2540)). If you `console.log(file.size)` you should see a value.
2. You have to `await` `user.upload()`.
3. You may need to call `userEvent.setup()`

I think a working version would be:

```js
const user = userEvent.setup()
const file = new File(["logo"], "logo.png", { type: "image/png" });
const imageComponent = screen.getByLabelText(/Profile Picture/i);

await user.upload(imageComponent, file);

expect(imageComponent.files[0]).toStrictEqual(file);
expect(imageComponent.files.item(0)).toStrictEqual(file);
expect(imageComponent.files).toHaveLength(1);
```